# Multiple HTML5 videos not loading

Tags: jquery, html, video

I've got some problems loading multiple HTML5 videos with the help of jQuery. I tried searching before on Google and Stackoverflow, but I didn't find the solution.

Anyways, I've got 2 buttons, when I click a button, then there opens a popup with a video tag. No problem to make, so I added a 'rel' attribute with the name of the movie file on the div.

When opening one div (it gets the active class), I make a source tag with the Append function in jQuery, which fills in with the rel:

```
    var target = "videos/" + $(this).find("#videoplayer").attr("rel");
    $(".active video").append('<source src="' + target + '"  type="video/webm">');
```

and then I use .remove() when I close the div, done.

Opening the first button with the video works instantly perfect. However, opening the second button: the video doesn't even start. All I see is a frozen screen.

Refreshing the page and opening the second button doesn't work either, it's again frozen and the first one works perfect. I don't know what the problem is with the second video but it's weird..

I've got the scripts uploaded in jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/5xmbu3nL/

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: ID's are unique, you can only use the same ID **once**. You need to use classes instead

Comment: @adeneo I'm only using '#videoplayer' once in my HTML, if you're talking about that? I'm not repeating it.

Comment: Well, then you could replace `$(this).find("#videoplayer")` with just `$('#videoplayer')` as finding a single element makes no sense. Did you open the console (F12) and check for errors

Comment: @adeneo oh crap, sorry. I was tired, but I indeed was using the IDs multiple times. Anyways, I changed them to classes now. But the problem still exists. :/